# Horizontally scroll an absolutely positioned element?

Tags: html, css

What is wrong with the code below? The desired behavior is for the `#library` element to span the bottom of the "screen" and scroll horizontally.

```css
#library {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
 height: 60px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

body { overflow: hidden; }

.item {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50px; height: 50px;
 margin: 5px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="library">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.item` elements wrap when they reach the end of the `#library`. You can't see the multiple lines of wrapped elements because of the `overflow-y: hidden`. Add `white-space: nowrap;` to `#library` to prevent the items from wrapping.

```css
#library {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="library">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```